# Grouping values based on other list

Tags: python

Grouping the list values according to group names:

```
groups = ['a','b','c','a','b','b']
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The out text file  should look like this:

```
a 1 4
b 2 5 6
c 3
```

---

```
with open ('out.txt','w') as fo:
   fo.write(group + str(values) + '\n')
```

Comment: `zip` them together to get an iterable of `(group, value)` tuples, then use `itertools.groupby`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function and `dict.setdefault` method to group your values in a dictionary then write the items to file :

```
>>> groups = ['a','b','c','a','b','b']
>>> values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> 
>>> d={}
>>> 
>>> for i,j in zip(groups,values):
...   d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
... 
>>> d
{'a': [1, 4], 'c': [3], 'b': [2, 5, 6]}



with open ('out.txt','w') as fo:
   for k,v in d.items():
        fo.write(k +'  '+ ' '.join(map(str,values)) + '\n')
```